# How to convert unicode array to string in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, unicode

I am very new with Python and I am trying to print a single object from a unicode array that I retrieved from my server. My array look like this when I print the results:

```
{u'results': [{u'playerName': u'Sean Plott', u'score': u'12'}]
```

I would like to print the result in `playerName` as a string only. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why convert it? You are also missing a closing brace. Should be: `{u'results': [{u'playerName': u'Sean Plott', u'score': u'12'}]}`

Comment: Are you just looking to print it pretty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should spend some time looking up dictionaries and lists in python. You currently have a dictionary with a list in it, and a dictionary inside of that list.

Here's the official reference guide on Python data structures:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

That being said, here's an example:

```
>>> d = {u'results': [{u'playerName': u'Sean Plott', u'score': u'12'}]}
>>> d["results"]
[{'score': '12', 'playerName': 'Sean Plott'}]
>>> d["results"][0]["playerName"]
'Sean Plott'
```

Comment: He has a list with a dict inside it you mean

Comment: He has a dict with a list with a dict in it

Comment: Thanks, this got me to where I wanted to! Thumbs up